# Create Private blockchain network using ganache

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, blockchain, private-blockchain, ganache

I am working on Truffle framework for creating DApps. My Question is that,In ganache can I use my private blockchain network address instead of testrpc accounts.Suppose I use private blockchain network address in ganache how can I access it publicly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the intro, Ganache CLI, part of the Truffle suite of Ethereum development tools, is the command line version of Ganache, It is personal blockchain for Ethereum development.  see this document on [Using Genache Cli](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) .  I guess You are asking about
 `--account:` Specify `--account=...` (no 's') any number of times passing arbitrary private keys and their associated balances to generate initial addresses:

```
$ ganache-cli --account="<privatekey>,balance" [--account="<privatekey>,balance"]
```

you can specify the host so it may possible to access publicly.

```
-h or --host or --hostname: Hostname to listen on. Defaults to 127.0.0.1.
```